# Cobertura Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/LightClassmapListener

Tags: java, ant, cobertura, system-testing, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am trying to build a jar file with Cobertura and I am getting this error when I run the file.

I downloaded all the files and put them all together in my '/lib' folder; so I have all Cobertura files there.

Here is my **build.properties** file

```
# Project Variables
src.dir=src
classes.dir=bin
dist.lib=dist/lib
dist=dist
lib=lib


# Cobertura 
cobertura.dir=lib
cobertura.ser=cobertura.ser
instrumented.dir=instrumented
reports.dir=reports
reports.xml.dir=${reports.dir}/junit-xml
reports.html.dir=${reports.dir}/junit-html
coverage.xml.dir=${reports.dir}/cobertura-xml
coverage.summaryxml.dir=${reports.dir}/cobertura-summary-xml
coverage.html.dir=${reports.dir}/cobertura-html


#Class main entries
class.main.main=server.controller.AccessControlMain


# Manifest properties
manifest.build.by=Alfredo Lopez
manifest.created.by=Team 4
manifest.main.class=${class.main.main}
```

And here is my ant **build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project default="pack-jar" name="main_ant">

    <property file="build.properties" />

    <path id="cobertura.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${cobertura.dir}">
            <include name="/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="build.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
          <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef classpathref="cobertura.classpath" resource="tasks.properties" />

    <target name="cobertura-all">
        <antcall target="cobertura-init"></antcall>
        <antcall target="cobertura-compile-debug"></antcall>
        <antcall target="cobertura-instrument"></antcall>
        <antcall target="cobertura-pack-jar"></antcall> 
    </target>

    <target name="cobertura-init">
        <echo>Making directories...</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${instrumented.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports.xml.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports.html.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${coverage.xml.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${coverage.summaryxml.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${coverage.html.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="cobertura-compile-debug">
        <echo>Compiling files with debug ...</echo>

        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" 
                destdir="${classes.dir}" 
                debug="on" 
                classpathref="build.class.path" 
                includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cobertura-instrument">
        <echo>Instrumenting files:</echo>
        <delete file="cobertura.ser" />
        <delete dir="${instrumented.dir}" />

        <cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}" datafile="${cobertura.ser}" >
            <ignore regex="org.apache.log4j.*" />
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
                <exclude name="**/*Test.class" />
            </fileset>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="cobertura.classpath"></path>
            </classpath>
        </cobertura-instrument>
    </target>

    <target name="cobertura-pack-jar">
        <echo>Packing cobertura</echo>

        <!-- Covert build class path to a string -->
        <pathconvert property="manifest.classpath" pathsep=" " >
            <path refid="build.class.path" />
            <flattenmapper />
        </pathconvert>
        <tstamp />

        <jar basedir="${instrumented.dir}" destfile="${dist}/PantherLot_Main_Cobertura.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${manifest.build.by}"/>
                <attribute name="Created-By" value="${manifest.created.by}"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${manifest.main.class}" />
                <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="cobertura-report">
        <delete dir="${report.dir}" />
        <cobertura-report format="html" destdir="${reports.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Any type of help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the Cobertura .jar files are under the `lib` directory. What version of Cobertura is in this directory?

Comment: I am using cobertura 2.1.1